# React Router Dom not rendering components but changes URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was pushing code into github when somehow my react router code stopped working. The components are not rendering yet the url is changing. Even when I replace  with a basic html tag, nothing renders. I am really lost and could use some help.

Dashboard.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Home from './Home/homeDashboard.jsx'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Map from '@material-ui/icons/MapOutlined';
import Test from './MyPlan/Modules.jsx';

function Dashboard() {

  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/home",
      main: () => <Home />
    },
    {
      path: "/myplan",
      main: () => <Test />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', height: '100vh' }}>
          <Router>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <nav className={classes.nav}>
                <IconButton className={classes.navBtn} component={Link} to="/home" style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)" }} >
                  <Tooltip title="Home" className={classes.toolTip}>
                    <HomeIcon />
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>

                <IconButton className={classes.navBtn} component={Link} to="/myplan" style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)" }}>
                  <Tooltip className={classes.toolTip} title="My Plan" >
                    <Map />
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
              </nav>
              <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Switch>
                  {routes.map((route, index) => (
                    <Route
                      key={index}
                      path={route.path}
                      children={<route.main />}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: You have to import `IconButton` and `Tooltip` components from material-ui.

Comment: I removed this part of the code because of the amount of code I had. That is not the issue, please disregard my imports

Comment: shouldn't it be `children={route.main}`  instead of `children={<route.main />}? ` is your linter / compiler not throwing any error about this?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar was following this tutorial: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/sidebar

Comment: following from the same URL, you are missing `exact=route.exact` from the tutorial, that might be causing an issue, where you are directed to the first page in your array

Comment: thanks for everyone's help. I was able to figure out the issue. I moved my <Switch> outside of the sidebar section. By leaving it in there, it rendered the component INSIDE the sidebar which hid it